# IE7, third and the following element rendered incorrectly

Tags: internet-explorer-7

I've got a requirement to render input type submit in UL > LI > INPUT. Hence the following HTML and CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/d45BY/1/

```
<ul class="listCell">
<li class="listCell bulletPoint">
<input id="cmd1" class="" type="Submit" value="Cmd1Text" name="cmd1">
</li>
<li class="listCell bulletPoint">
<input id="cmd2" class="" type="Submit" value="Cmd2Text" name="cmd2">
</li>
<li class="listCell bulletPoint">
<input id="cmd3" class="" type="Submit" value="Cmd3Text" name="cmd3">
</li>
<li class="listCell bulletPoint">
<input id="cmd4" class="" type="Submit" value="Cmd4Text" name="cmd4">
</li>
</ul>

.bulletPoint {
    list-style: disc outside none;
}
```

This renders fine on most browsers except IE 7 in compatibility mode. Im running IE8.0.7601.17514. 
When I select Browser mode IE7 and Document mode IE7 standards the following happens:

Items 1 and 2 render fine. 3 goes to the left and then 4 goes even further to the right. Just wondering if anyone has seen this issue or can replicate it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had the input types rendered to look like links. For some reason it always rendered the 3rd and subsequent item in all different places. The fix I did was the following"

```
text-align: left
```

What that does is that it keeps the text inside the button to left. Problem solved. Hope this helps someone.